# Conversation Uniqueness

Tags: lync, lync-2010

I have an application in which I have subscribed for ConversationAdded and ConversationRemoved.

I want to maintain a list of dictionary of conversation which i received from ConversationAdded event and remove it from the list of once i get the ConversationRemoved Event.

So my question-> Is there some way we can find some uniqueness or some key of Conversation which i can get and add it in the list. And when i get the conversation removed event i can use that key from the conversation object received and remove the conversation object from the list.

Please let me know your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an comment which can be considered as answer

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/f174c3fa-f93a-4bd9-a0a2-641510720001

Comment: [Never just post a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/307961). Add a short summary in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, there's a ConversationID you can get. From the ConversationAdded event, you can get it with this:

```
string ConversationID = e.Conversation.Properties[ConversationProperty.Id].ToString();
```

More info and a proper walk-through [on my blog here](http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2013/01/tracking-lync-conversations-in-code/).

Comment: Hi, 
The MSDN site for Microsoft Lync says that "Id" or the conversation identifier is not constant and can change throughout the life of the conversation.
"[ConversationProperty.Id]"
So can we consider it as as unique identifier or the key while storing the conversation.

Moreover i have observed that in Conversation_Removed, we get ConversationProperty.Id as null. It happened with me in Lync 2013.
                                                                    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversationproperty_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx

Comment: Here is a comment from another forum  which can be considered as answer <http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/f174c3fa-f93a-4bd9-a0a2-641510720001>

Comment: i'm aware that the conversationID can change if the conversation is escalated to conference etc. However, in simple 2-person calls, I've not seen the conversation ID change before (but that doesn't really mean anyway). Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a better ID. You could maybe store the sender and receiver of the conversation and use that as a key? I'm not 100% sure if Lync allows multiple conversations between the same people (I don't see why not)